# Collar between shower drain and p-trap?

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent, connectors, p-trap, abs

[image]I am renovating a small bathroom, including a shower.  I am needing to replace the shower drain assembly, but it is a very tight area to do much work in, with no access from underneath.  The current drain is 2” (it appears) ABS that was glued together.  A P-trap is installed, and we’ve had no issues with the flow of water out of the existing shower (knock on wood).  So I think the p-trap is in good shape.

Since it is too tight of quarters to replace the entire trap, I was hoping to cut the drain line off between the shower floor and p-trap, glue a collar onto the trap and connect my new drain to that collar (all joints glued w/ ABS cement, obviously).  Does that meet code and is there anything I need to watch out for?

Comment: glueing is permanent, so if you have a leak you are screwed. Since the drain has no pressure consideusing seals instead of glue.

Comment: Any drain work that is done in an enclosed area (no direct access after shower is finished) should most certainly be glued together.

Comment: Pics of what you're looking at, with some arrows and hand drawn red circles to indicate what you're intending to do would help immensely. You can [edit] your question, then use the "sun & mountain" icon to add the pics in, or (from a non-phone/tablet) just drag and drop the images into the text edit box.

Comment: FreeMan, I added a pic with a red line of where I’m hoping to make the cut

Answer (score 0):

If a "collar" is the same thing as a "coupling" (which is a fitting that joins one pipe to another pipe) then that is fine.

You have not said what drain or shower you are installing- a tile shower pan or a fiberglass pan ? They have different drain pieces needed. The thing to watch out for is whether there is enough vertical room to get your "coupling" and whatever else you need to hook up your drain and have it be at the correct height for your shower.

Comment: An alternative to gain room is to use a "hub saver" or "socket saver" tool to bore out the old pipe connecting to the P-trap so you can connect a new pipe directly to it, rather than needing a coupling.

Comment: Kyle-yes, my mistake…I meant coupling.  That’s why I shouldn’t be trying to proofread when it’s past my bedtime!  As for the replacement, I plan to use a fiberglass shower pan (Kerdi).

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of rubber coupling is the simplest, direct and effective method of doing it.
There is also clearly enough pipe still left to do the same thing as you see there now.
There is a good 1 to 1 1/2 exposed pipe there at the moment.  If there is some old glue in the way, simply file it off and you are good to go.

Either way, it is smooth sailing for you.

Take care.